# Cannot execute /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory on ubuntu server using RVM

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, server

I am trying to run rails app in production on Ubuntu server, but it shows message that something went wrong. And in apache logs i found this:

> An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read Raw process output:
>
> ```
>  * ERROR *: Cannot execute /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
> ```

Note that i am using rvm and my ruby path is different

Using SSH everything works fine.

Comment: Seems like Physion Passenger is looking in that *specific* location for the ruby executable. Other SO'ers will likely know how to specifically make phusion point at your custom ruby path but, until then, you might be able to hack around it by soft linking ruby to that path, e.g. `ln -s /your/path /usr/bin/ruby` in the terminal (if that helps!)

Comment: thank you, something happend but now i have permission denied :( hopefully i will figure something out. Thank you very much for such easy solution :D

Comment: Permission denied means, you have to create the link with super user rights, since normal users don't have write access to `/usr/bin`.
So actual command would be `sudo ln -s /your/path /usr/bin/ruby`